# gxp_GoogleStreetViewPanel

Tags: geoext, boundless-suite, google-street-view

is there any available example online, or anybody could help me to figure out how can I use the GoogleStreetViewPanel widget in the opengeo suit sdk? I tought it will work like this:

```
{
        xtype: "gxp_googlestreetviewpanel"
}
```

but this code generate me an error about missing lan/lot...
I could manage to add other widgets, like scaleoverlay.

Comment: The previous code in which part of the app goes thanks

Answer (score 1):

The street view panel is tied to a location on the map, e.g. a point where the user clicked. This needs to be passed on.

This application has an example: http://sfpark.org/ and the source code of that application can be found here: https://github.com/boundlessgeo/sfpark.org

```
    this.popup.add({
        xtype: "gxp_googlestreetviewpanel",
        zoom: 1,
        heading: this.getOrientationForFeature(this.feature),
        location: new OpenLayers.LonLat(geom.x, geom.y)
    });
```